# Why is the program keeping output the same value?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 0.625, E = 0.0001;
    double value[2] = { 1 / x, 0 };
    for (int count = 0; ; count++)
    {
        value[1] = ((3 / 2) * value[0]) - ((1 / 2) * x * pow(value[0], 3));
        cout << value[1] << value[0];
        value[0] = value[1];
    }

}
```

Why doesn't value[1] change its number, if there is the instruction that does some calculations?(the eighth line)

Comment: Side note: you have an infinite loop there

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know about problem with the second element of the "value" array

Comment: Unrelated: You will not be happy with `cout << value[1] << value[0];`. Let's say it prints `3.141592.71828`, where does the second number starts? Is it `2.7` or `92.7` or .... ?

Answer (score 2):

`(3 / 2)` and `(1 / 2)` are integral operations and do not produce fractional results. They do not produce `1.5` and `0.5` like you expect; they return `1` and `0`, cancelling out half of your calculation.

Try instead with `(3.0 / 2)` and `(1.0 / 2)`

...or simply `1.5` and `0.5`.

Comment: `(3 / 2)` is `1`.

Comment: And to get not integer number, I need to use number with point, like 1.5 and 0.5